# Error in mutate() while calculating fold change in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as follows:

```
barcode <- c("barcode1", "barcode1", "barcode2", "barcode2", "barcode3","barcode3","barcode1","barcode1","barcode2","barcode2","barcode3","barcode3")
sampleID <- rep(paste0("sampleID_", 1:12))
bc_rel_abun <- runif(length(sampleID), min = 0, max = 1)
Nature <- rep(c("Control", "Case"), each = 6)        
df <- data.frame(barcode, sampleID, bc_rel_abun,Nature)
```

My sample data frame looks like this:

```
barcode     sampleID    bc_rel_abun Nature  
barcode1    sampleID_1  0.41882879  Control
barcode1    sampleID_2  0.83716346  Control
barcode2    sampleID_3  0.67896128  Control
barcode2    sampleID_4  0.39580917  Control
barcode3    sampleID_5  0.98048215  Control
barcode3    sampleID_6  0.79361367  Control
barcode4    sampleID_7  0.81375412  Case
barcode4    sampleID_8  0.26496766  Case
barcode5    sampleID_9  0.01611351  Case
barcode5    sampleID_10 0.11424951  Case
barcode6    sampleID_11 0.22295376  Case
barcode6    sampleID_12 0.26514516  Case
```

In the next step, I created a mean column for each barcode for both control and case groups using the following command:

```
df<- df %>% 
    group_by(barcode,Nature) %>% 
    mutate(bc_rel_abun_repli_comb = mean(bc_rel_abun))
```

So my input would be:

```
barcode sampleID    bc_rel_abun Nature  bc_rel_abun_repli_comb
barcode1    sampleID_1  0.52943005  Control 0.2787944
barcode1    sampleID_2  0.02815876  Control 0.2787944
barcode1    sampleID_7  0.07202808  Case    0.3977409
barcode1    sampleID_8  0.7234538   Case    0.3977409
barcode2    sampleID_3  0.91049034  Control 0.5937941
barcode2    sampleID_4  0.27709792  Control 0.5937941
barcode2    sampleID_9  0.35682787  Case    0.2408962
barcode2    sampleID_10 0.12496456  Case    0.2408962
barcode3    sampleID_5  0.80824273  Control 0.859509
barcode3    sampleID_6  0.91077533  Control 0.859509
barcode3    sampleID_11 0.59845722  Case    0.3807016
barcode3    sampleID_12 0.1629459   Case    0.3807016
```

Then, I tried to calculate the fold change between Control and Case for each barcode in my dataset using the mean column as follows:

```
 df %>% 
      group_by(barcode) %>% 
      mutate(foldchange = (bc_rel_abun_repli_comb[Nature == "Control"] - bc_rel_abun_repli_comb[Nature == "Case"]) / bc_rel_abun_repli_comb[Nature == "Control"])
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
    Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `foldchange = ... / bc_rel_abun[Nature == "Control"]`.
ℹ In group 1: `barcode = "AAAAAAAAAGATAATTTACATTAGG"`.
Caused by error:
! `foldchange` must be size 4 or 1, not 2.
```

Output would be:

```
barcode Nature  Foldchange
barcode1    Controlvscase   2.7
barcode2    Controlvscase   -0.3
barcode3    Controlvscase   0.2
```

Can anyone help me understand what this error means and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your question to make this reproducible? Its close, but not yet reproducible

Comment: I can't run your sample data code with the `...` in it to actually check anything or try a solution, but it seems strange that you have 2 observations for each barcode/Nature combo. I'd suggest adding a row number within the groups you have and then grouping by that as well.

Comment: As to the error, the way you calculate `foldchange` (within a single `barcode` group) the resulting length is 2. `bc_rel_abun[Nature == "Control"]` is length 2, you subtract something of length 2, and you divide by something of length 2. But the whole group input is length 4 (2 case + 2 control). `dplyr` doesn't allow recycling like base R unless the length is 1. Hence the error, *`foldchange` must be size 4 or 1, not 2.* If you want the recycled you could wrap it in `rep()` and repeat it explicitly. Or if you want something else, you should show the desired result.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have modified my input. Should I first find the average of each barcode with control and case separately and then calculate FC

Comment: Your initial code doesn't have any averages and you haven't shown the desired result. If you want an average then you should certainly use the `mean()` function somewhere. `(mean(y) - mean(x)) / mean(y)` generally different than `mean((y - x) / y)` - I can't tell you which one you want.

Comment: With your edits, I don't think the code works at all - barcodes 1, 2, 3 are only in the `control` group and 4,5,6 are only in the `case` group. Before it seemed like you wanted the foldchange calculated for each barcode individually, but now there are no barcodes in both case and control... Showing your desired output for this sample input would help clarify.

Comment: @GregorThomas I hope my edit clearly explains my need. kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I considered your edit and came up with this. Generally, you are using `mutate`, whereas you should use `summarise` instead. Hope this solves your issue. On why your code didn't work, check the comments.

```r
library(tidyverse)

barcode <- c("barcode1", "barcode1", "barcode2", "barcode2", 
             "barcode3","barcode3","barcode1","barcode1","barcode2",
             "barcode2","barcode3","barcode3")
sampleID <- rep(paste0("sampleID_", 1:12))
bc_rel_abun <- runif(length(sampleID), min = 0, max = 1)
Nature <- rep(c("Control", "Case"), each = 6)        
df <- data.frame(barcode, sampleID, bc_rel_abun,Nature)       



df %>% 
  group_by(barcode, Nature) %>% 
  summarise(bc_rel_abun_repli_comb = mean(bc_rel_abun)) %>%
  group_by(barcode) %>%
  summarise(foldchange= diff(bc_rel_abun_repli_comb)
            /bc_rel_abun_repli_comb[Nature == "Control"])
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'barcode'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   barcode  foldchange
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 barcode1     -0.949
#> 2 barcode2     -0.107
#> 3 barcode3      0.479
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>